# Calculate gross pay, savings and investment

Tags: java

I would appreciate any advice to help me figure out how to get rid of the two sets of decimals for "the IRA investment amount" and "Total of savings and IRA amounts".

The expected output I'm trying to reach is:

```
Enter the gross pay: 
Enter the savings rate %: 
Enter the IRA rate %: 
Gross pay: 1000.0
Savings rate %: 10.0
Savings amount: 100.0
IRA rate %: 5.0
IRA investment amount: 50.0
Total of savings and IRA amounts: 150.0
```

I keep getting this output:

```
Enter the gross pay: 
Enter the savings rate %: 
Enter the IRA rate %: 
Gross pay:4 $1000.0
Savings rate %: 10.0
Savings amount: 100.0
IRA rate %: 5.0
IRA investment amount: 100.050.0              // See here
Total of savings and IRA amounts: 100.050.0   // See here
```

This is what I have wrote so far.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main_02 {

public static void main (String[]args) {

    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
    double grossPay = 0.0;        // First number to average
    double savingsRate = 0.0;     // Second number to average
    double iraRate = 0.0;         // Average of the input values
    double savingAmt = 0.0;
    double iraAmt = 0.0;
    double totalSavings = 0.0;


    // Input the two numbers
    System.out.print("Enter the gross pay: ");
    grossPay = console.nextDouble();

    System.out.print("Enter the savings rate %: ");
    savingsRate = console.nextDouble();

    System.out.print("Enter the IRA rate %: ");
    iraRate= console.nextDouble();

    // Calculate the average of the two numbers

    savingAmt = (grossPay * savingsRate) / 100.0;

    iraAmt = (grossPay * iraRate) / 100.0;

    totalSavings = math.ceil(savingAmt + iraAmt);

    // Output the results
    System.out.println("Gross pay:4 $" + grossPay);
    System.out.println("Savings rate %: " + savingsRate);
    System.out.println("Savings amount: " + savingAmt);
    System.out.println("IRA rate %: " + iraRate);
    System.out.println("IRA investment amount: " + savingAmt + iraAmt);
    System.out.println("Total of savings and IRA amounts: " + savingAmt + iraAmt);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is being converted to a String

```
System.out.println("IRA investment amount: " + savingAmt + iraAmt);
```

so change to

```
System.out.println("IRA investment amount: " + (savingAmt + iraAmt));
```

May I also suggest that you use `System.printf` for the last line as being

```
System.out.printf ("Total of savings %f and IRA amounts %f %n", savingAmt , iraAmt);
```

If you only want `iraAmt` (50.0) to print then do not add `savingAmt` to it

```
System.out.println("IRA investment amount: " + (iraAmt));
```

Comment: not stated though in the problem but seems like the next line OP is willing to print different strings only

Comment: I cant figure out how to put the input that I'm getting now so I'll try and put them up in different strings

Comment: Expected output
IRA investment amount: 50.0

Comment: why add `savingAmt` to it then?

Comment: I'm new to this so I can't explain.  Plus this is out of the book.  I just need to get the expected output "IRA investment amount: 50.0"  instead of 150.0.  Not even sure how to do it.

Comment: So it would look like this   System.out.println("IRA investment amount: " + (iraAmt + savingAmt));

Comment: No, why are you adding `+ savingAmt` ??  See my edited answer

Comment: I'm sorry.  I didn't follow what you were talking about at first.  I see what you are talking about and your suggestion fixed the problem.  Sorry if explaining this to me was difficult.  Again, I'm new at this.  Thank you very much...again.

Comment: If this answer helped you please consider to upvote and/or accept this answer

Answer (score 0):

You're ending up adding two strings instead when you use `savingAmt + iraAmt` concatenated with a string `" "` before them.

```
Savings amount: 100.0 
IRA rate %: 5.0

i.e. 100.050.0
```

**According to the expected output**, you might want to change

```
System.out.println("IRA investment amount: " + savingAmt + iraAmt);
System.out.println("Total of savings and IRA amounts: " + savingAmt + iraAmt);
```

to

```
System.out.println("IRA investment amount: " + iraAmt);
System.out.println("Total of savings and IRA amounts: "  + (savingAmt + iraAmt));
```

Comment: That didn't work.  I still have the output of "IRA investment amount: 150.0" instead of 50.0

Comment: @MattHurt Updated the answer according to the expected output.

Comment: @MattHurt Cool. if that helps you, do mark it as an answer to help future readers. :)